# Formatting a data structure on php back-end in order to read it in Flutter client

Tags: php, json, flutter

I have an issue with reading data from API back-end to Android Flutter front-end. Back-end is written in php and it looks as bellow:

```
....

echo json_encode($login_data); // sends logged user status

....

$statement = $conn->prepare($SQL);
$statement->bindParam(':email', $user, PDO::PARAM_STR);
$statement->execute();
$result = $statement->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);

if ($result) {
    foreach($result as $row) {
        $return_arr[] = array(
                       "email" => $row['emailP'],
                       "data" => $row['dataP']
        );
    }
    echo json_encode($return_arr);
}
```

Data structure is:

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [email] => some.name1@gmail.com
            [data] => 2023-09-27 20:22:42
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [email] => some.name2@gmail.com
            [data] => 2023-09-27 20:22:42
        )

    [2] => Array
        (
            [email] => some.name3@gmail.com
            [data] => 2023-01-08 15:47:19
        )

)
```

I got an 'Unexpected character' eror message as listed bellow:

```
I/flutter (  857): FormatException: Unexpected character (at character 65)
I/flutter (  857): {"success":1,"user":{"imie":"Name1","email":"abcdef@gmail.com"}}[{"lista":"...
I/flutter (  857):                                                                 ^
```

As far as I understand it, flutter complains about an array that is sent from back-end, but I do not know how to force him to read it properly.

The way I read the data in Flutter is:

```
....

final response = await get(
          Uri.parse('https://www.somehost.com/API/abc.php'),
          headers: {
          'Content-Type': 'application/json',
          'Accept': 'application/json',
          'Authorization': 'Bearer $token',
          }
        );

      var data = jsonDecode(response.body.toString());

      print(data);

      if(response.statusCode == 200){
        if(data['success'] == 1) {
          print(data['user']['email']);     
          print(data['data']);          // this does not work

        } else {
          print(data['status']);
          print(data['message']);
        }
      }else {
        print('Login failed...');
        print(response.statusCode);
      }

....
```

Could you please help me and advice on how to adjust data structure on back-end in order to read it properly on Flutter client?

Comment: You can't output two entirely separate JSON objects in a single response and expect a JSON parser to be able to understand it. It doesn't form a coherent single JSON object (or array), so it's not readable. The parser has no idea there are two separate JSON entities in the data. So you could just remove `echo json_encode($login_data);`. I assume that's maybe only there for your debugging? If not, then you'll need to merge that data with the list data into a single PHP data structure, and then json_encode the combined data at the end, to get a single JSON entity in your response.

Comment: OK... I understand... I will remove first JSON, the second one is IMPORTANT. Thank you for helping :)

Comment: No worries. If you still need to output other things for debugging purposes, I suggest making PHP log the content to a file instead.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't output two entirely separate JSON objects in a single response and expect a JSON parser to be able to understand it. It doesn't form a coherent single JSON object (or array), so it's not readable. The parser has no idea there are two separate JSON entities in the data. So you could just remove `echo json_encode($login_data);`. I assume that's maybe only there for your debugging?

If not, then you'll need to merge that data with the list data into a single PHP data structure, and then json_encode the combined data at the end, to get a single JSON entity in your response.